# Show validation message when rule triggered

Tags: php, cakephp

so if i have the following validation rule in my `Forward` model

```
    public $validate = array(
    'url' =>array(
        'rule' => 'url',
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid Url.'
    )
);
```

and i want to display the message in a flash how do i achieve that?

I have tried the following:

```
        $new_forward = $this->request->data;
        $this->Forward->create();
        $this->Session->setFlash($this->Forward->save($new_forward));
```

Also tried this with no result

```
$this->Session->setFlash($this->ModelName->validationErrors);
```

Comment: make sure session helper is added...also `$this->Session->setFlash($this->Forward->save($new_forward));` is wrong `$this->Forward->save($new_forward)` will return true or false base on successful execution of code.

Comment: @DipeshParmar Session helper is added.. do you know how i can display the message?

Comment: see my answer i have added code in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using below sample code,

```
$this->Forward->create();
if ($this->Forward->save($this->request->data))
{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Forward has been saved', true),'flash_success');
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'forwards','action' => 'index'));
}
else
{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Forward could not be saved. Please, try again.', true),'flash_error');
}
```

Comment: this is good for a hardcoded response but what i wish to return is the message which i set in my validation rule ie:    public $validate = array(
    'url' =>array(
        'rule' => 'url',
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid Url.'
    )
);

Comment: so you can add `$this->ModelName->validationErrors` line inplace of static error i set

Comment: So this is valid:    $this->Session->setFlash(__($this->ModelName->validationErrors, true),'flash_error');

Comment: @DipeshParmar You should mention that `flash_success` and `flash_error` are custom view elements that would need to be created first! Also instead of saying "_you can place this and that_" it would be better to update your example, it doesn't answer the question the way it is right now. Also the message for the specific field would need to be extracted from the `validationErrors` array, you can't simply pass the array to `setFlash()`